Problematic optimization of excited states
I work with Orca 5.0.4 (without access to version 6.0) on a symmetric metal-centered system. I'm currently running excited state optimizations, and while S1-S3 and T1, T2, and T4 have optimized flawlessly, T3, T5, and T6 are not converging.
So far, I've tried switching to internal coordinates instead of XYZ coordinates and lowering the maxstep parameter to 0.2. The main part of my input is:
! PBE0 D4 def2-SVP def2/J GCP(DFT/SVP) RI-SOMF(1X)
! OPT FREQ CPCM(WATER)
%BASIS
    NEWGTO Cu "def2-TZVP" END
END
%TDDFT
    NROOTS X+5
    DOSOC TRUE
    IROOT X
    IROOTMULT TRIPLET
END

What are the other options I could consider?

Hi farmaceut, would you be able to clarify which part of the calculation won't converge? Is it the geometry optimisation procedure, the calculation of the excited states, or the frequency calculation?

Hi, @leeman
The problems regard optimization steps. Forgot to mention, I also tried multistep job with the first one using def2-SVP in vacuum, and without success

Hi @farmaceut, thanks for clarifying. These higher energy excited states can be tricky to optimise sometimes. Have you already tried taking the partially optimised geometry from one of the failed calcs and resumbiting? Something that's all you need to get them to converge...

@leeman Yes, I have tried but they keep oscillating without a success in convergence.

Hi @farmaceut, if two or more excited states are close in energy, they might switch order. Not sure how ORCA is doing it, but if you always use the gradients of the, say, 5th excited state, it might change places with one or several other excited states during the optimization. This will lead to oscillations as you described it. Is there an option in ORCA to use the maximum overlap of a transition vector or excited state density instead of the order of the excited state energies? Other QC packages do offer that, so it might be available in ORCA too.

Hey @Uwe. I've managed to install ORCA 6.0.0 where (what a luck!), FOLLOWIROOT was introduced (vide page 215 of the newest manual). I suppose this is what you are referring to, aren't you?

Hi @farmaceut, I just checked the online manual of ORCA 6 and yes, this is exactly what I was referring to. I like the disclaimer in the manual (that it does not solve all your problems) as I used to use this approach a few years back and it did help in most cases, but occasionally it failed to converge too.

@Uwe  Unfortunatelly, I cannot optimize S2 !  Wonder what to do. Using keywords: NROOTS 7 IROOT 2 FOLLOWIROOT TRUE.

@farmaceut I thought you have already optimized S2 with the default settings? I'd use the usual approach and only try the new option for those cases which failed. If both fail the system might be running into a conical intersection or instabilities of the ground state density, or another of the many possible complications.

@Uwe, Yes, I though S2 optimized well but checked later and was wrong. So basically, this is S2 and T3. The latter is more important because the system follows Kasha's rule and T3 is below S1. IROOT changes quite often in the output so maybe that's the problem and it oscillates between many-different? After all, the energy difference between e.g. T3 and T4 is in hundredths of eV... Though, I am no sure how am I supposed to know if IROOT has changed to the incorrect (or correct) one?

I was going to say the same as Uwe: how sure are you that the excited state electronic structure remains the same? Second thing: do the problematic states break symmetry?

Justin Talbot and I found that excited state optimizations sometimes attempt to painfully (oscillatoring-ly) arrive to these "fake" wells near conical intersections.
https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0172015
At the points where your optimization has come closest to convergence, how nearby are the other states? If they are very close, you may be running into the same issue. Not sure if ORCA has analytic TDDFT Hessians but if it does, it may be a good idea to check all your minima to make sure they are not "fantastical" (giant second derivatives) or else calculate non-adiabatic couplings. You could also spot-check the partially-optimized structures that are giving you trouble. If it is indeed the situation, you'll see the massive modes / strong NACs already in the vicinity of the "minima".
